# Sorted JSON Still Partially Out of Order

Tags: php, json, sorting

I am trying to parse iTunes Search album/track information. The track listing comes in out of order, and when I try to order by track number, it is still slightly out of order.

For example, I am parsing this:

```
$url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=band+name&entity=song';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

asort($data['results']);

if(!empty($data['results'])) {
  foreach($data['results'] as $album) {
    echo '<p>'.$album['trackNumber'].'. '.$album['trackName'].'</p>';
  }
}
```

The track number result is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 11. For some reason 12 is displaying before 11. What is the reason for this?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think `asort` does what you think it does. You should probably be using `usort`. That 1-12 happen to be in the order they are I expect is just a coincidence.

Comment: From what I can tell from the JSON provided by `$url` there isn't really any sorting happening from `$data['results']`, as there is no value to sort in that array. What if you actually sorted it by track number: `asort($data['results']['trackNumber']);`?

Comment: Tried `usort` and I still get the same results. as for `asort($data['results']['trackNumber']);` I get the error: `Warning: asort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`.

Comment: `Tried usort and I still get the same results` Seems unlikely.But looks like it's sorted.

Comment: Writing `usort` function the way I did, was giving the same results as just the `asort` I originally posted. I then adjusted as Paolo did below, and that worked. I think all I was missing to add was the the `['trackNumber']` index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sort the array by the value of a specific key (`trackNumber` in your case) you need to use [**`usort`**](http://php.net/usort), and a comparison function (`cmp` in the example below)

```
$url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=band+name&entity=song';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

usort( $data['results'], 'cmp' );

if(!empty($data['results'])) {
  foreach($data['results'] as $album) {
    echo '<p>'.$album['trackNumber'].'. '.$album['trackName'].'</p>';
  }
}


// comparison function

function cmp( $a, $b )
{
    if ($a['trackNumber'] == $b['trackNumber']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['trackNumber'] < $b['trackNumber']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Here's what you get

```
1. Glorious Day (feat. Kristian Stanfill)
1. New Feeling
1. Rocket Science (feat. Tyler Eads)
1. What Yo Name Iz? (Remix) [feat. Wale, Big Sean and Bun B]
2. A Clean Break (Let's Work) [Live]
2. Worthy of Your Name (feat. Sean Curran)
3. Don't Worry About the Government
3. How Great Is Your Love (feat. Kristian Stanfill)
4. Pulled Up
4. Build My Life (feat. Brett Younker)
[...]
```

Note you have more tracks with the same track number.

That's because the results you get are tracks from different albums.

You may need to filter your results before sorting or improve the comparison function.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!